# Asserting Rest Assured response with Json Unit

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I'm currently using rest assured and Json-unit to assert a local json file against the requested rest assured response.

I currently have a before class method with my base uri.

I don't know how to make this assertion. I'm struggling with the json-unit documentation. Do I need to input a file first?

```
    @Test
    public void ApiaryTest1() throws Exception {

        when()

                .get("/test")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);

        // compares two JSON documents
        assertJsonEquals("expected/test.json", "http://apiary/test");
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm struggling"?

Comment: So I've got it calling apiary. I've got it coming back with a 200 response. I now want t use this json-unit to check the expected file against the rest response. How do I do that? becuase the json-unit documentation isn't particularly clear in my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Read in the resource with the JsonUnit API
- Extract the response from rest assured to a variable
- Assert you are already doing

Example:

```
Response response = when().get("<url>");
        response
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);

        // compares two JSON documents
        assertJsonEquals(resource("resource-inside-resources-folder.json"), response.asString());
```

Comment: Hi this just gives me this error now however thank you for you reply.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(Ljava/io/Reader;)V

Comment: objc[45956]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(Ljava/io/Reader;)V

Comment: What serializer are u using? Jackson, gson or another?

Comment: That solved it I didn't have the Jackson dependency in my POM. My bad.

Comment: You could use `extract().response();` to get the response using the Fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

For Restassured Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
        When {
            get("http://nowjidev1vm01.ath.bskyb.com/calskyplussearch/health")
        } Then {
            statusCode(200)
        } Extract {
            assertJsonEquals(expectedBody, response().asString())
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than you think. Rest Assures is passing the entire body as string in case of a "body matcher" is specified. Therefore you can just use the *jsonEquals* matcher of json unit directly:

```
import static net.javacrumbs.jsonunit.JsonMatchers.jsonEquals;

public class RestAssuredWithJsonUnit {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        
        given().when().get("/api/service/v1").
                then().
                statusCode(200).
                body(jsonEquals(resource("resource-on-classpath.json")));

    }

    public static String resource(String resourceName) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(resourceName, "'null' passed instead of resource name");
        return IOUtils.resourceToString(resourceName, UTF_8);
    }
```

Please note the implementation of the "resource" method. The one provided in *ResourceUtils* is using the system classloader, which did not found my resoulces unfortunately. IOUtils from commons-io does the job well!